# preg_match_all pattern to get phone numbers

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have tried many many times to use `preg_match_all` for getting some phone numbers.

The things i want to get, with no problem is these structures :

```
09123456789
+989123456789
989123456789
0912 345 6789
+98 912 345 6789
```

How can i use preg_match_all to find the top numbers ?

they may have spaces or not.

All of them maybe start with `+98` OR `98` For country code,

And then phone **number Must start with `9` OR `0`.**

I have tried like this: (But it does NOT work for all)

```
/[+989][09]*([0-9]{9,})/i
```

Comment: did you want to find the number which starts with `0`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj No, it may start with 9 or 0

Comment: `And then phone number Must start with 9` ?
Please add some sample strings which should matches your pattern, also which should not match your pattern

Comment: @AvinashRaj sorry thats wronge, i'll fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
(?:\+?98|0)(?:\s*\d{3}){2}\s*\d{4}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qO9gE5/2)

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOT
09123456789
+989123456789
989123456789
0912 345 6789
+98 912 345 6789
EOT;
$regex =  '~(?:\+?98|0)(?:\s*\d{3}){2}\s*\d{4}~';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09123456789
            [1] => +989123456789
            [2] => 989123456789
            [3] => 0912 345 6789
            [4] => +98 912 345 6789
        )

)
```

Comment: `And then phone number Must start with 9 OR 0.`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(((\+?98)?|0) ?9[\d ]+)
```

See demo: http://regex101.com/r/rG6qE8/1

Comment: thanks, but a problem is that it gets some spam values, How can i set the length must be more than 5 ?

Comment: You can add {5,} at the end or replace the + with {9,} like you had it.

Comment: `\d{9,}` will match `9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999`, is this a valid phone number?